# how to bind 2 classes at the same time?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I need to make background color blue if element is current (`bg-blue-400`), green background (`bg-green-400`) - completed, dark (`bg-dark-400`) - uncompleted (only one can be activated). Example what I want:

[image]

My code:

```
<div v-bind:class="{'bg-blue-400' : isSelected(task), 'bg-grey-400' : isNotCompleted(task)}" 
class="icon-block s30 text-white" >{{index+1}}</div>
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: First : end your first line `isNotCompleted(task)"` with `isNotCompleted(task) }"`

Comment: ended, but the same result

Comment: Why not put this logic not within the template but within a method (computed)?, then return the css class name as result.

Comment: thats good idea, answer this question or I`ll do this a little bit later

Comment: @MAXIMAN can you show `isSelected`  and `isNotCompleted` methods ?

Comment: See my answer, it should get you going :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put this kind of logic within your script tag, and not within your template.

Based on the type of behaviour you want you need to choice between putting your logic within a computed property or method. (ask yourself the question: do you want the css class to change when your task changes? if so use computed property otherwise use a method)

Another improvement (since you are using a v-for) is to put your individual tasks in component.

Tasks component:

```
<task v-for="task in tasks" :task="task"></task>
```

Task component:

```
<template>
    <div v-bind:class="cssClass">
    <p> {{ task.name }} </p>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    computed: {
      cssClass: function () {
        return {
         'bg-blue-400' if this.task.selected
        }
      }
    }
</script>
```